# For Google App Engine (java), how do I set and use chunk size in FetchOptions?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, chunking

Im running a query and it is currently returning 1400 results and because of this I am getting the following warning in the log file:

> com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultsSourceImpl
>   logChunkSizeWarning: This query does not have a chunk size set in
>   FetchOptions and has returned over 1000 results.  If result sets of
>   this size are common for this query, consider setting a chunk size to
>   improve performance.

I can't find any examples anywhere as to how to actually implement this, there is a question on here about python, but as Im using java and dont understand python, I am struggling to translate it.

Also this query (below) is taking 17226cpu_ms to execute, which feels like way too long, I cant even imagine what would happen if I had say 5000 contacts and needed to search through them on the client side (like you do with googlemail contacts!)

The code I have is:

```
    int index=0;
    int numcontacts=0;
    String[][] DetailList;

    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();


    try {
        Query query = pm.newQuery(Contact.class, "AdminID == AID");
        query.declareParameters("Long AID");
        query.setOrdering("Name asc");
        List<Contact> Contacts = (List<Contact>) query.execute(AdminID);
        numcontacts=Contacts.size();
        DetailList=new String[numcontacts][5];

        for (Contact contact : Contacts) 
        {
            DetailList[index][0]=contact.getID().toString();
            DetailList[index][1]=Encode.EncodeString(contact.getName());
            index++;
        }
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
    return (DetailList);
```

I found the following two entries on here:

- [google app engine chunkSize & prefetchSize - where can I read details on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914069/google-app-engine-chunksize-prefetchsize-where-can-i-read-details-on-it)
- [GAE/J Low-level API: FetchOptions usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995302/gae-j-low-level-api-fetchoptions-usage)

but neither actually goes into any details about how to implement or use these options.
Im guessing its a server side process, and Im guessing that you are meant to setup some kind of loop to grab the chunks one chunk at a time, but how do I actually do that?

- Do I call the query inside a loop?
- How do I know how many times to loop?
- Do I just check for the first chunk that comes back with less than the chunk size number of entries?

How am I meant to go about finding out stuff like this without an actual example to follow? 
It seems to me that other people on here seem to "just know" how to do it..!

Sorry If I am not asking the questions in the right way or I'm just being a dim newbie about this, but I dont know where else to turn to figure this out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meeting the same problem and the last comment was from a month ago, so here is what I found out about heavy dataset query.

I guess I'm gonna use the "Query cursor" technique after reading those lines in the google docs [article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/paging) (the one in python mentioned by the way) :

> This article was written for SDK version 1.1.7. As of release 1.3.1,
>   query cursors ([Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Query_Cursors) | [Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Query_Cursors)) have superseded the techniques described
>   below and are now the recommended method for paging through large
>   datasets.

In the google docs about "[Query Cursor](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Query_Cursors)". 
The first line of the doc gives precisely why the need for *cursor* :

> Query cursors allow an app to perform a query and retrieve a batch of
>   results, then fetch additional results for the same query in a
>   subsequent web **request without the overhead of a query offset**.

The documentation provides also a **java example** of a servlet using the cursor technique. There is a tip how to generate a safe cursor for the client. Finally, limitations of *cursor* are exposed.

Hope this gives you a lead to resolve your problem.

Small reminder about range and **offset**, quite impacting on performance if forgotten (and I did^^) :

> The starting offset has implications for performance: the Datastore
>   must retrieve and then discard all results prior to the starting
>   offset. For example, a query with a range of 5, 10 fetches ten results
>   from the Datastore, then discards the first five and returns the
>   remaining five to the application.

---

Edit : As working with JDO, I kept looking for a way to allow my previous code to load more than 1000 result in a single query. So, if you're using JDO too, I found this old [issue](http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=208):

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(...);
// I would use of value below 1000 (gae limit) 
query.getFetchPlan().setFetchSize(numberOfRecordByFetch);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I apply `FetchOptions`, compared to your example code, you might need to tweak a bit:

```
// ..... build the Query object
FetchOptions fetch_options =
    FetchOptions.Builder.withPrefetchSize(100).chunkSize(100);
QueryResultList<Entity> returned_entities =
    datastore_service_instance.prepare(query).asQueryResultList(fetch_options);
```

Of course that the figures may be changed (100).

If my answer isn't what you're looking for then you're welcome to rephrase your question (edit).

By the way I'm the one who wrote the first linked question.

Comment: I'm not sure how to rephrase my question, so Im just going to reply to your comment. Am I meant to just replace my one line of code: "List<Contact> Contacts = (List<Contact>) query.execute(AdminID);" with your two lines of code? If so can you help me by changing your code to match the variables in mine? as I cant work it out. I have tried about 20 combinations of my variables but nothing makes any sense, which is kind of why I was asking the above questions...One thing I have hit a couple of times seems to be to do with the fact that my "Query" above is imported as "javax.jdo.Query;"

Comment: Can anyone help me with this as its now causing me a problem I cant workaround anymore!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the dataStore directly, *without* JDO, then you would do something like the following to set the chunk-size when you are iterating through the data:

```
Query query = new Query("entityname");
PreparedQuery preparedQuery = dataStore.prepare(query);
// the 200 should be less than 1000
FetchOptions options = FetchOptions.Builder.withChunkSize(200);
for (Entity result : preparedQuery.asIterable(options)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I hate to say it, but I never did figure out how to do this, I just had a customer call up to say that this problem has raised its ugly head again...

They are gathering 2044 data records from App engine and I'm getting the error again to set the chunk size to avoid the problem... 

Essentially I am getting a timeout on the loading of the data & still don't really understand how to solve the problem, for me it's the "..." bit in your for loop above that I don't know how to handle. Will the datastore return the results in 200 chunks, do I then recombine them before sending them to the client?

Comment: Yes, I'd recombine them @johnvdenley.   You are breaking up the query so it finishes faster and then combining the results to equal the entire list.